# Square root of a squared block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

I’m trying to compute the square root of the following squared block matrix:

\begin{equation}
M=\begin{bmatrix}
A &B\\
C &D\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

(that is $M^{1/2}$) as function of $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ wich are all square matrices.

Can you help me?

I sincerely thank you! :)

All the best

GoodSpirit

Comment: "The square root" is meaningless - there are potentially infinitely many square roots to a matrix.

Comment: If $M$ was symmetric and positive definite, then there is a unique positive definite square-root of $M$.  For that you need to assume $B=C^\top$ and $A,D$ must be positive definite.

Comment: I really thank your answers! Peter, that is precisely the case. M is a covariance matrix but positive semi-definite. A and D are symmetric and positive semi-definite(covariance matrices too) and $$B=C^T$$ and B is the cross covariance matrix of A and D. My attempt is based on eigendecomposition $$ M=Q \Lambda Q^T $$
and $$
M=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$ But it lead to something very complicated. I really thank you all for your answers!:) All the best GoodSpirit

Comment: How did you get your last equation which contains $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$? What are they?